# What is wrong with my url (google place api and retrofit)

Tags: android, google-places-api, retrofit

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=45.537284299999996,-73.576391125&radius=1000&types=amusement_park|restaurant|cafe|restaurant|library&rankby=distance&key=apikey

I'm using retrofit. Here is my code:
Retrofit api interface:

```
ublic interface PlaceApiRequestInterface {

@GET("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json")

//synch request: all wait on the same thread
public Response getJson(@Query("location") String location,
                        @Query("radius") String radius,
                        @Query("rankby") String rankby,
                        @Query("types") String types,
                        @Query("key") String key);
```

}

Then how I set my values

```
       LatLng locationLatLong = obtenirLeCentre(membres);
    String location = locationLatLong.latitude+","+locationLatLong.longitude;
    //radius_
    String radius = ""+radius_;
    //rankby_ is an attribute whose value is "distance"
    //type
    Set<String> uniqueElements = new HashSet<String>(listPreferences_); 
    listPreferences_.clear();
    listPreferences_.addAll(uniqueElements);
    String type = "";
    int taille = listPreferences_.size();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < taille; i++){
        if(i == taille - 1)
            type += Converter.converter_.nameToPlaceType(listPreferences_.get(i));
        else
            type += Converter.converter_.nameToPlaceType(listPreferences_.get(i))+"|";
    }
    setupClient();

    //2- get the answer from my http call
    String reponseHttp = Converter.converter_.fromResponseToString(get().getJson(location,radius,rankBy,type,googleKey));
```

I get this as an answer:

> {
>      "html_attributions" : [],
>      "results" : [],
>      "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
>   }
>   Blockquote

Can one help me to discover what is wrong here? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with just one types? Try to manipulate the url to see what fits and then work backwards.

Comment: Following on from what @luke_mclachlan has said check out this post https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4056 one user in particular suggested "You should not provide a radius if using rankby=distance." i would give this a test run now but i don't have an api key to hand.

Comment: I don't know if it is normal, but when I remove "rankby=distance" I get a good answer with the "OK" status.

Comment: As some one said here : [link]http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4056   #15 luizsoliveira : "the rankby parameter is not accepted by the search text, only the simple search"
I suppose that it applies to the "nearby" search that I'm using.